# Why can I not append two variables as a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
list = []
tuples = ((0,1),(1,1),(2,2),)
x = 0
y = 2
list.append([[], tuples + (x,y)])
print(list)
```

Im using This code as part of a tic tac toe AI to construct a tree however when appending this new list to the main list the tuples value reads as ((0,1),(1,1),(2,2),0,2). I intend for the x and y variables to be as part of a single tuple like so:((0,1),(1,1),(2,2),(0,2))
What am I doing wrong here? thank you in advance

Comment: `tuples + ((x,y),)`

Comment: If you have a tuple of the things and a tuple of two things, you'll end up with a tuple of five things.

Comment: @Sukumar *builtin, not keyword. Keywords can't be overridden.

Comment: @wjandrea I was talking about the variable `list`.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf: `list` is the name of a built-in, but it isn't a keyword. That was wjandrea's point. The reason this is a problem is because `list` *isn't* a keyword, which means you *can* (but shouldn't) name stuff with it.

Comment: I named these for demonstration purposes, they are named differently in the actual program. How do you suggest I name them in a stack overflow question?

Comment: Why are you appending a list, that contains an empty list and a new tuple, to *another* list?

Comment: It is very likely not an efficient way of doing so but I am using nested lists to create a tree of possible outcomes for tic tac toe then using a recursive minimax function to choose the best possible move. The list in the 0th element will be the list to store all possible moves from the current node in the tree. The tuple in the 1st element is basically the instructions for all the moves to get to that node in the tree with each nested tuple as a coordinate on a 3x3 tic tac toe board. If there are any suggestions on how I could do it more efficiently help would be appreciated

Comment: @Numdoo We're just mentioning about `list` for your sake. In a short example it doesn't really matter, but you could use like, `lst` or `list_` if you want to avoid annoying comments ;)

Comment: Your current output looks identical to your desired output. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
list = []
tuples = ((0,1),(1,1),(2,2),)
x = 0
y = 2
list.append([[], tuples + ((x,y),)])
print(list)
```

Comment: adding some text might be helpful